# Server/ Client Socket Programming and mysql database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sockets

I am working on client/server socket programming. Android Client and Java Server on my laptop. I want to send several images through socket from Android device to a Java server which saves each image in a MySQL database as blob. I close the client socket for each image transfer and reconnect again for the next image transfer.

My first image transfer works fine and is saved in the MySQL database but when I try to reconnect socket to server and transfer a different image I get  **Connection reset**.

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Error reading from InputStream java.net.SocketException
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.readblock(PreparedStatement.java:3099)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.streamToBytes(PreparedStatement.java:5106)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2575)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2366)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2350)
at Uploadpic.run(Uploadpic.java:113)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.readblock(PreparedStatement.java:3097)
... 7 more










 public class Uploadpic extends Thread  {
private Socket socket1 =null;

//public  Client user = new Client();
public Uploadpic(Socket socket1)
{
    this.socket1 = socket1;
}

public void run() {
    int imagenum = 0;
    String mes = null;
    BufferedReader buff;
    int imagesize = 0;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        buff = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(socket1.getInputStream()));
        while ((mes = buff.readLine())!= null)
        {
            if(!mes.equals(null))
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("image size is =" + mes);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imagesize = Integer.parseInt(mes);

    try {

         is = socket1.getInputStream();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users";
    String dbUser = "root";
    String dbPwd = "daniere";
    boolean check = false ;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs;    
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [imagesize];
    int rowCount = -1;

  String INSERT_PICTURE = 
                    "INSERT INTO USERPICS (id_PIC,user_id,picname)values (?, ?, ?)";

    try
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, dbUser, dbPwd);
        try {
            while(check == false)


            conn.setAutoCommit(true);

        ps = (PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_PICTURE);

            System.out.println("     ");
            ps.setInt(1,imagenum);
            ps.setInt(2, DataBase.user.getClientId());
            ps.setBinaryStream(3, is, (int) mybytearray.length);

              **ERROR HAPPENS HERE**int s = ps.executeUpdate();

            if(s>0) {
                System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
                }
                else {
                System.out.println("unsucessfull to upload image.");
                }
        } finally {

            try {
                ps.close();
                ps = null;
                is.close();
                //socket1.close();
                socket2.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        if (conn != null)
        {

            conn.close();
            conn = null;

        }
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) 
    {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }

}

   }
```

Comment: We don't need images. Just post the exact, full, error you're getting and the code where the error is happening.

Comment: Are you doing multiple threaded insertions?

Comment: yes that's right.Android client transfers image file in new thread. After the first image is passed the client closes the socket and  current Activity, so i can press again on upload button to send more images.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to multi-threading issues. I guess that you spawn one thread for inserting each picture, because of `Uploadpic extends Thread` (btw [it's recommended to implement Runnable instead of extending Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)), and also I suspect that

`DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, dbUser, dbPwd)`

is returning same connection if one is already open for this URL.

If this is the case, a possible race condition can appear where two threads are using the same `Connection` object referenced by `conn`, and one closes it while the other is still working with it.

*Solution*: No need to open/close the connection for each picture, that's useless work: open DB connection when you start the server and close it when you exit.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot your comment helped me to solve the problem :)